# Prettify OS X console by coloring output?

Tags: terminal, color, console

OS X terminal is not using colors for highlighting output from different commands, for example `ls`.

When compared with other systems like Ubuntu, this is a big loss of accessibility/productivity.

What solutions do I have to improve this experience? For the moment I found only this guide for [colored ls output under OS X](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031027145026892) but I am looking for a more complete solution.

Answer (score 25):

- you should change the Terminal.app preferences->advanced into xterm-color.
- enter the following into your ~/.profile

for enable colored `ls`:

```
export CLICOLOR=1;
export LSCOLORS=exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad;
```

and from now, you will get colored `ls` output.

Comment: +1 For proper terminal colour definitions. In general colours are personal but I would recommend to enable features more on a system-based way than by adding a plugin.

Comment: +1 - Does what it says on the tin. Cheers. A question: Where would I put such a config file at a more general level (i.e. not in ~)?

Comment: IMHO the your $HOME/.profile is the best place, but if you want can put them into system wide `/etc/profile`. e.g. sudo open /etc/profile

Comment: Note that prior to Lion, the default $TERM value is xterm-color, so you rarely need to change it. As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal's default $TERM value is xterm-256color, which enables programs that can take advantage of the extended 256 color palette. On Lion and later, using xterm-color is discouraged, because it describes an older, less-featureful branch of xterm, and Lion Terminal is more compatible with modern xterm. So you should generally stick with xterm-256color or just xterm.

Comment: You can create your own color scheme with this [online tool](http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/)

Answer (score 6):

You can easily change the ls output color by installing "TerminalColors" plugin. I am a big fan of "[Solarize](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized)" theme which looks terrific on my Mac.

Comment: Looks nice. Will try it this evening.

Comment: +1 thanks, Solarize is nice and I will use it, but the question was not about how to "tune" the colors, it was about adding colors to the output of different commands.